# Swift Ui Firebase array is empty when my view loads

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Swift Ui im using firebase to get data from the database and when I print it out in the method it shows my array but its empty when my swift ui view loads and I don't know why can someone help me please. Thanks

HomeProductViewModel.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class HomeProductViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var ProductList = [Product]()
    
    func getLatestProductList(){
            self.ProductList = []
            let productRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Products")
            productRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
                if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                    for data in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                        if let data = data.value as? [String: Any]{
                            let productName = data["name"] as! String
                            let photoLink = data["image_link"] as! String
                            let price = data["price"] as! Int
                            let productToAppend: Product = Product(name: productName, imageLink: photoLink, price: price)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.ProductList.append(productToAppend)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    }

}
```

HomeScrollView.swift

```
struct HomeScrollView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var HomeVM: HomeProductViewModel = HomeProductViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(HomeVM.ProductList){ product in
            HStack{
                RemoteImageView(url: product.imageLink)
                Text("\(product.name)")
                VStack{
                    Text("Price: $\(product.price)")
                }
            }.font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.title/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/).onAppear(perform: {
                self.HomeVM.getLatestProductList()
                print(HomeVM.ProductList)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set up `.environmentObject(_:)` to ensure that your SwiftUI view is accessing the correct version of `ProductList`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/environmentobject(_:)

Comment: im not using environment object here this is an observed object for this view

Comment: Three things: First `self.ProductList.append(productToAppend)` shouldn't be in a DispatchQueue. Second force unwrapping optionals is dangerous and will crash your code `data["name"] as!` should be `data["name"] as? String ?? "some default"`. Last, why are you populating an array in `.font`?

Comment: I fixed this using an escaping closure